# SASI Indexes in Cassandra seem to have some bugs

Tags: cassandra, secondary-indexes

I just started working with the SASI index on Cassandra 3.7.0 and I encountered a problem which as I suspected was a bug. I had hardly tracked down the situation in which the bug showed up, here is what I found:

When querying with a SASI index, **it may incorrectly return 0 rows**, and changing a little conditions, it works again, like the following CQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS roles (
    name text,
    a int,
    b int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((name, a), b)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (b DESC);

insert into roles (name,a,b) values ('Joe',1,1);
insert into roles (name,a,b) values ('Joe',2,2);
insert into roles (name,a,b) values ('Joe',3,3);
insert into roles (name,a,b) values ('Joe',4,4);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS roles2 (
    name text,
    a int,
    b int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((name, a), b)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (b ASC);

insert into roles2 (name,a,b) values ('Joe',1,1);
insert into roles2 (name,a,b) values ('Joe',2,2);
insert into roles2 (name,a,b) values ('Joe',3,3);
insert into roles2 (name,a,b) values ('Joe',4,4);

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX ON roles (b) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' 
WITH OPTIONS = { 'mode': 'SPARSE' };
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX ON roles2 (b) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' 
WITH OPTIONS = { 'mode': 'SPARSE' };
```

Noticing that I only change table ***roles2*** from table ***roles***'s '***CLUSTERING ORDER BY (b DESC)***' into '***CLUSTERING ORDER BY (b ASC)***'.

When querying with statement `select * from roles2 where b<3;`, the rusult is two rows:

```
 name | a | b
------+---+---
  Joe | 1 | 1
  Joe | 2 | 2

(2 rows)
```

However, if querying with `select * from roles where b<3;`, it returned no rows at all:

```
 name | a | b
------+---+---

(0 rows)
```

This is not the only situation where the bug would show up, one time I created a SASI index with specific name like 'end_idx' on column 'end', the bug showed up, when I didn't specify the index name, it gone.

Please help me confirm this bug, or tell me if I'd used the SASI index the wrong way.

Comment: You should probably file this as a JIRA ticket on the OSS C* jira.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel

Comment: @RussS I just wanted to make sure this is a bug rather than I somehow messed up in some places. I will take your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: It looks like @Qiuzd filed this as [CASSANDRA-12223](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12223), for anyone who encounters the question later. (I just experienced the same bug and ended up here).